# Fetching multiple items in React/Redux causing infinite loop and no jsx on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

Goal:

I want to be able to fetch multiple profiles from an array and list them out on the screen. Something like:

```
John, Sandy, Drew
```

I am using react and trying to list out users from a `friendRequest` array. This array is filled with user id's and I want to map over them to get the user and show him/her on the screen.

What is happening is that in the `console.log(pendingFriend)`, it is a infinite loop of in this case two profiles over and over again getting logged. Also no jsx is being displayed on the screen.

Here is the code.

Look in the render > return > where you see the `currentUser.friendRequests` being mapped over.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

import actions from '../../actions';
import { UpdateProfile } from '../view';
import { DateUtils } from '../../utils';

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      profile: {
        image:
          'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/EJf2u6azJe-TA6YeMWpDtMHAG6u3i1S1DhbiUXViaF5Pyg_CPEOCOEquKbX3U-drH29oYe98xKJiWqYP1ZxPGUQ545k',
        bannerImage:
          'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RAdfZt76XmM5p_rXwVsfQ3J8ca9aQUgONQaXSE1cC0bR0xETrKAoX8OEOzID-ro_3vFfgO8ZMQIqmjTiaCvuK4GtzI8',
        firstName: 'First Name',
        lastName: 'Last Name',
        email: 'Contact Email',
        bio: 'Bio will go here'
      }
    };

    this.deleteProfile = this.deleteProfile.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    if (this.props.profiles[id] != null) {
      return;
    }

    this.props
      .getProfile(id)
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  createUpdatedProfile(params) {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const profile = this.props.profiles[id];
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;

    if (currentUser.id !== profile.id) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'You do not own this profile',
        icon: 'error'
      });

      return;
    }

    this.props
      .updateProfile(currentUser, params)
      .then(response => {
        swal({
          title: `${response.username} Updated!`,
          text: 'Thank you for updating your profile',
          icon: 'success'
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  deleteProfile() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const profile = this.props.profiles[id];
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;

    if (currentUser.id !== profile.id) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'You do not own this profile',
        icon: 'error'
      });

      return;
    }

    swal({
      closeOnClickOutside: false,
      closeOnEsc: false,
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text:
        'All data related to profile will be deleted as well with the profile! If you wish to delete your profile you must type DELETE',
      icon: 'warning',
      dangerMode: true,
      buttons: true,
      content: 'input'
    }).then(value => {
      if (value === 'DELETE') {
        const userPosts = this.props.post.all.filter(p => p.profile.id === profile.id);
        const userReplies = this.props.reply.all.filter(r => r.user.id === profile.id);
        userPosts.map(post => {
          this.props.deleteRecord(post);
        });
        userReplies.map(reply => {
          this.props.deleteReply(reply);
        });
        this.props
          .deleteProfile(profile)
          .then(data => {
            return this.props.logoutUser();
          })
          .then(data => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
            swal('Deleted!', 'Your Profile has been deleted.', 'success');
            return null;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
      swal({
        title: 'Profile not deleted',
        text: 'Make sure you type "DELETE" with caps',
        icon: 'error'
      });
    });
  }

  addFriend() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const profile = this.props.profiles[id];
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;
    if (currentUser == null || profile == null) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'Must be logged in, and user must exist',
        icon: 'error'
      });
      return;
    }
    const friendRequests = profile.friendRequests || [];
    const params = {};
    friendRequests.push(currentUser.id);
    params.friendRequests = friendRequests;
    this.props
      .updateProfile(profile, params)
      .then(() => {
        swal({
          title: 'Success',
          text: 'Friend Request Sent',
          icon: 'success'
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const profile = this.props.profiles[id];
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;
    const defaultProfile = this.state.profile;
    const bannerUrl =
      profile == null
        ? defaultProfile.bannerImage
        : profile.bannerImage || defaultProfile.bannerImage;
    const bannerStyle = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${bannerUrl})`,
      backgroundSize: '100%',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: 'center'
    };
    const nameStyle = {
      background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
      borderRadius: '8px'
    };
    const imageStyle = {
      maxHeight: '150px',
      margin: '20px auto'
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {profile == null ? (
          <div>
            <h1>Profile no longer exists</h1>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {currentUser == null ? null : currentUser.id !== profile.id ? null : (
              <div className="list-group">
                {currentUser.friendRequests
                  ? currentUser.friendRequests.map(request => {
                      this.props
                        .getProfile(request)
                        .then(pendingFriend => {
                          console.log(pendingFriend);
                          return (
                            <div key={pendingFriend.id} className="list-group-item">
                              <p>{pendingFriend.username}</p>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log(err);
                        });
                    })
                  : null}
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style={bannerStyle}>
              <div className="container" style={nameStyle}>
                <img
                  src={profile.image || defaultProfile.image}
                  style={imageStyle}
                  className="rounded img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h1 className="display-3 text-center">{profile.username}</h1>
                <p className="lead text-center">
                  {profile.firstName || defaultProfile.firstName}{' '}
                  {profile.lastName || defaultProfile.lastName}
                </p>
                <p className="lead text-center text-muted">
                  {profile.email || defaultProfile.email}
                </p>
                <p className="text-center text-muted">
                  Became a User: {DateUtils.relativeTime(profile.timestamp)}
                </p>
                <hr className="my-4" />
                <p className="lead" style={{ border: '1px solid #e6e6e6', padding: '20px' }}>
                  {profile.bio || defaultProfile.bio}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            {currentUser == null ? null : currentUser.id !== profile.id ? (
              <div className="row justify-content-center" style={{ marginBottom: '100px' }}>
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                  {profile.friendRequests ? (
                    profile.friendRequests.indexOf(currentUser.id) === -1 ? (
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                        onClick={this.addFriend.bind(this)}
                      >
                        Add Friend
                      </button>
                    ) : (
                      <button className="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        Pending Friend Request
                      </button>
                    )
                  ) : (
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                      onClick={this.addFriend.bind(this)}
                    >
                      Add Friend
                    </button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <UpdateProfile
                  currentProfile={profile}
                  onCreate={this.createUpdatedProfile.bind(this)}
                />
                <div className="row justify-content-center" style={{ marginBottom: '100px' }}>
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"
                      onClick={this.deleteProfile}
                    >
                      DELETE Profile
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const stateToProps = state => {
  return {
    profiles: state.profile,
    user: state.user,
    post: state.post,
    reply: state.reply
  };
};

const dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getProfile: id => dispatch(actions.getProfile(id)),
    updateProfile: (entity, params) => dispatch(actions.updateProfile(entity, params)),
    deleteProfile: entity => dispatch(actions.deleteProfile(entity)),
    deleteRecord: entity => dispatch(actions.deleteRecord(entity)),
    deleteReply: entity => dispatch(actions.deleteReply(entity)),
    logoutUser: () => dispatch(actions.logoutUser())
  };
};

const loadData = store => {
  return store.dispatch(actions.getProfile(this.props.match.params.id));
};

export default {
  loadData: loadData,
  component: connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Profile)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is breaking the pattern in so many ways, i'm not sure where to start :)

- First of all as for your question about the infinite loop, you
  probably want to start with this line in your `render` method:

  ```
  this.props.getProfile(request)
      .then(pendingFriend => {   
       console.log(pendingFriend);
  ```

  You should never ever update the state or dispatch actions.
  These    are the two main ways to re-render a component, state change
  and new    props. When you dispatch an action you actually causing a
  new render    call as a new prop will be received to your connected
  component.      With that said, do not do async calls inside the
  render method,    [render method should be pure](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) with no side effects. 
  Async calls and data fetching should be triggered in
  `componentDidMount`.
- Another thing not related to your problem directly, most of your
  handlers are not `bind` the `this` object to the class, the only
  handler you did bind is `deleteProfile`. `bind` them all or use
  [arrow functions which will use the `this` in a lexical context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- Again, not related directly to your problem, always pass `props` when
  using the [constructor and super](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

  ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  ```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> is it okay if I directly bind the functions like
>   this.deleteProfile.bind(this) instead of doing this.deleteProfile =
>   this.deleteProfile.bind(this) in the constructor just do
>   this.deleteProfile.bind(this) inside the render method

This won't change anything as `bind` isn't mutating the function, instead it returns a new instance with the `this` object is attached to it (it uses `call` behind the scenes) you can see the [implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).
So you must override your handlers with the new instance.
By the way, inside your `render` function, doing binding or any other operation that will create a new instance of a function or object is less preferable as you will create new instance on each render call of course. if you can "lift" it up to a method like the `constructor` (which is called only once in a component's life time) is much more performant.

Comment: Even if this does not directly answer my question this is all good information and should give me a very good start thank you. I will accept when I can

Comment: The first section about `dispatching` in your render method is what causing your infinite loop. you are getting new `props` which cause the `render` method to get invoked again (and again.. and again..)

Comment: Also is it okay if I directly bind the functions like `this.deleteProfile.bind(this)`

Comment: what do you mean by bind it directly?

Comment: instead of doing `this.deleteProfile = this.deleteProfile.bind(this)` in the constructor just do `this.deleteProfile.bind(this)` inside the render method

Comment: you are the man , great explanations, learned some good stuff.

Comment: I'm glad i could help!